# Did pubnub store streamed big data?

Tags: bigdata, real-time, pubnub, mapbox-gl-js

i found out that pubnub is a solution to stream ***real time*** data to mapbox on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fufDOEEVwyE) .

But what about the storage?
Did pubnub store the data on a database so it can be analyzed later or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub Storage

When you publish message to PubNub, those messages can be stored for 1 to 30 days or forever. You can use the PubNub history and fecthMessage APIs of the PubNub SDKs to retrieve those messages. You can `deleteMessage`'s, too.

For more details on PubNub Storage, please see the [PubNub Storage & Playback Tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/tutorials/pubnub-storage-and-playback/). Each of the [PubNub SDK Docs has the full API details](https://www.pubnub.com/docs) for the respective language.